# Can I use this brand of bleach with some other ingredients to sterilise seed trays?

Tags: containers, germination

Where I live in Delhi, India, there is no pure bleach available. The only similar option is something called Rin Ala, which is a laundry liquid bleach with 4 percent Sodium Hypochlorite (bleach), 1 percent Sodium Hydroxide and an amine which I don't remember. Can I use this in a water based solution to bleach seed trays and pots? Or should I order Clorox from Amazon here which will take time and has complaints of leakage?

Comment: The "standard" method of sterilizing gardening equipment for many years on the UK was Jeyes Fluid (first produced in 1877!). The current EU safety and environmental regulations mean they can no longer advertise it for its original purpose, but it is still marketed. The original (concentrated) product which needs to be diluted about 100:1 for cleaning plant pots etc is much more cost effective than the "ready to use" versions.

Comment: I have used dettol after reading your comment. Composition is similar. Jeyes' fluid is not available here.